# How to plot a lagged time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw some quick graphs for exploratory analysis and have the following question:

How can I plot a lagged time series in ggplot? I am trying to do something like this:

```
 ggplot(data,aes(x=xdata,y=xdata-1)+geom_point()
```

But `xdata-1` is subtracting 1 from `xdata` instead of reading the previous `xdata` value.

`ggplot` does not seem to have a `lag.plot` equivalent and I did find a function called `gglagplot` in the `ggfortify` package that seems to be exactly what I want but that is not available in the latest version of R (currently 3.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tail` to get a lagged version a vector:

```
tail(x,-1)
```

But within `ggplot2` aesthetics must either be length one or having the same length, so you should append a value to the lagged one in order to plot it against the original vector. For example:

```
x= 1:10
qplot(x=x,y=c(tail(x,-1),0))
```

Another option , is to use `lag` function from `stats`, but this assumes you are dealing with time series objects.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It took me a while to figure out your comment that 'adding a value to the lagged one' means extending the column data by the number of lags as though it were a list, so I'm adding another example here for the benefit of other newbies: `qplot(x=x,y=c(tail(x,-2),0,0))`